# How can I split my Ruby on Rails 5 application into multiple folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application is getting bigger as it needs to manage more sujects:

- Common objects such as users and parameters
- Processes classification management
- A glossary of terms
- Etc.

Subjects are loosely coupled. For example, business processes descriptions contain highlighted words that link to the glossary.

I may appear to be maniac, but I'd like to organize my application into subfolders, such as:

```
app/models/processes_classification/business_area.rb

.................................../business_flow.rb

.................................../business_process.rb
```

But it seems that Rails does not dig that deep into folders hierarchies.
Which would be the best practice to structure a growing application, with loosely coupled subjects, where users and parameters are common to all?

I was thinking of:

having several applications with 1 central Devise instance (is it possible?)

or organizing folders hierarchies to match subjects

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can namespace your model by adding a folder in your `models` folder and putting all your namesapced models in `modules`.

So `app/models/business_area.rb` becomes `app/models/processes_classification/business_area.rb`

and inside the `business_area.rb` file

`class BusinessArea < ApplicationRecord
  ...
 end`

becomes:

`module ProcessesClassification
   class BusinessArea < ApplicationRecord
     ...
   end
 end`

That will autoload the BusinessArea model, just keep in mind that you will have to refer to it as `ProcessesClassification::BusinessArea` not just `BusinessArea`